# Need to draw bottom border on the last row on each page in html/css

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am  dynamically generating pdf from  HTML which has content that might run across pages.I am using IE11.

When there is a table that runs to multiple pages, the bottom border of the last row is not shown in each broken page. The bottom border appears only in the last page or where the table is closing.

Is there any way to apply bottom border in this case.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Actually its large html file which produces final pdf.

Comment: I even tried tfoot but didnt work..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put javascript part and (border-collapse) in css. I have written other css just for styling.

```js
var $foo = $('#foo');
var bodyLastRow = $foo.children('tbody').children('tr:last-child');
bodyLastRow.css({
  'border-bottom': '1px solid #555'
});
```

```css
#foo {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#foo thead tr { 
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.6);  
}

#foo tbody tr { 
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);  
}

#foo tbody tr td, #foo thead tr td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="foo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashish</td>
      <td>ashish@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Asdh</td>
      <td>asdh@outlook.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

$('table#foo tbody tr:last-child').css({
      border-bottom: #555
    });